# Can't update User belongs_to association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I've got a page where a User (using Devise) sets up multiple preferences through checkboxes and then radio buttons of predefined data. So far I have the user able to update a has_and_belongs_to_many association but I can't get my belongs_to one's working.

At the moment I've got this error with the following parameters shown:

```
PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR: insert or update on table "users" violates foreign key constraint

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "user"=>{"sport_ids"=>["4"], "goal_ids"=>["6"], "moment_id"=>"moment_id", "workout_id"=>"workout_id"},
 "commit"=>"Save Changes",
 "id"=>"1"}
```

It seems clear that I'm not passing an id number through but I don't know how to fix it. When I don't get an error nothing happens.

Here are my files

## models/user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :city
  belongs_to :workout
  belongs_to :fitness_level
  belongs_to :moment

  has_and_belongs_to_many :sports
  has_and_belongs_to_many :goals
  has_and_belongs_to_many :gyms
end
```

## controllers/users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

...

def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @auth = current_user.id

    # To make sure you can't edit someone elses profile
    if @auth != @user.id
      redirect_to @user
    end

    @sports = Sport.all.order(name: :asc)
    @goals = Goal.all.order(name: :asc)
    @workouts = Workout.all.order(:name)
    @moments = Moment.all

  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    if @user.update(user_params)
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(sport_ids: [], goal_ids: [])
    params.require(:user).permit(:workout_id, :moment_id)
  end
end
```

## users/edit.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>


# The following two work
<% @sports.each do |sport| %>
    <%= check_box_tag "user[sport_ids][]", sport.id, form.object.sports.include?(sport) %>
    <%= sport.name %>
  <% end %>

<% @goals.each do |goal| %>
    <%= check_box_tag "user[goal_ids][]", goal.id, form.object.goal.include?(goal) %>
    <%= sport.name %>
  <% end %>

# the below doesn't work

<% @moments.each do |moment| %>

      <%= radio_button_tag 'user[moment_id]', :moment_id %>

    <h4><%= moment.name %></h4>

<% end %>  <!-- end moments-->

<% @workouts.each do |workout| %>

      <%= radio_button_tag 'user[workout_id]', :workout_id %>   

<% end %>  <!-- end workouts-->
<% end %> <! -- end form -->
```

I have some important styling with the forms using tags so that will need to stay.

**EDIT: Adding Users table in schema**

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.jsonb    "settings",               default: {}, null: false
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.date     "date_of_birth"
    t.integer  "city_id"
    t.text     "bio"
    t.integer  "workout_id"
    t.integer  "fitness_level_id"
    t.integer  "moment_id"
    t.index ["city_id"], name: "index_users_on_city_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
    t.index ["fitness_level_id"], name: "index_users_on_fitness_level_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["moment_id"], name: "index_users_on_moment_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree
    t.index ["settings"], name: "index_users_on_settings", using: :gin
    t.index ["workout_id"], name: "index_users_on_workout_id", using: :btree
  end
```

Comment: which database are you using? PostgreSQL ?

Comment: hey I'm using postgres

Comment: Have you tried `<%= radio_button_tag 'user[moment_id][]', moment.id %>` or `<%= radio_button_tag 'user[moment_id]', moment.id %>` ? In `users/edit.html.erb`

Comment: I have yes :( Using that code submits the form but those radio tag associations arent saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im pretty sure the problem in that line:

```
<%= radio_button_tag 'user[moment_id]', :moment_id %>
```

You dont pass moment_id and workout_id from the view to controller`s update action.

Try to change it to:

```
<% @moments.each do |moment| %>

    <%= radio_button_tag 'user[moment_id]', moment.id %>

    <h4><%= moment.name %></h4>

<% end %>  <!-- end moments-->
```

The same is for workout:

```
<% @workouts.each do |workout| %>

      <%= radio_button_tag 'user[workout_id]', workout.id %>  

<% end %>  <!-- end workouts-->
```

Also why dont you pass permitted params in one line? Like this:

```
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:moment_id, :workout_id, sport_ids: [], goal_ids: [])
  end
```

Comment: When passing the params in one line I get this: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting => [], goal_ids: [], :moment_id, :workout_id) ^

Comment: however seems to work with both lines? It IS now updating but each time I go back to my edit page the radio buttons aren't selected, making it look like nothing happened to the user.. Any idea why this is? (also really appreciate your time, thanks)

Comment: @SamPrice yeah my bad. This one is correct `params.require(:user).permit(:moment_id, :workout_id, sport_ids: [], goal_ids: [])`

Comment: Amazing! It all works. To get the radio button selected I made the code: <%= radio_button_tag 'user[moment_id]', moment.id, f.object.moment(moment) %> - thank you so much. it all works finally. I'll mark your answer now